# access value in array from Json response angular 4

Tags: json, angular, http, typescript

i wanna display a field in array at table .. how can i access SubjectCode in my Json Response using angular 4 ? .. My code give me error [Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed]

Json Response :

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Council_ID": 88,
  "place": "bla bla",
  "number": "45",
  "type": 1,
  "date": "2017-11-08T00:00:00",
  "time": "04:51",
  "user_Id": 15,
  "subjects": [
     {
        "$id": "2",
        "subjectCode": "45",
        "type": 1,
        "faculty": "medicine",
        "branch": "اسكندرية",
        "gender": true
     }
 ],
  "absence": []
}
```

meeting.component.html:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed text-center">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let subject of subjectsWithID">
                                    <td > {{subject.subjects.subjectCode}} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

meeting.component.ts:

```
this.dataStorageService.getCouncilId(this.meetingID).subscribe(response => {
                    this.subjectsWithID = response.json();
                    console.log(this.subjectsWithID, 'all Json Resopnse Here')
                });
```

Comment: What does your console log displays ?

Comment: it displays json response @trichetriche

Comment: you're using *ngFor over an object not an array. You should use `subjectsWithID.subjects` on your *ngFor

Comment: yes , Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ngFor over subjects, code should be,

```
<tr *ngFor="let subject of subjectsWithID.subjects">
   <td > {{subject.subjectCode}} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `subjects` property is an array. If you want to display it, then you should do

```
{{subject.subjects[0].subjectCode}}
```

Comment: Well because you use ngFor on an object, not an array.

Comment: Great, rememebr to mark @Sajeetharan's answer as resolved !